# Trying to remove libtinfo5 in Ubuntu, but got a unmet dependencies error

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I tried to run the following command:

```
apt-get remove libtinfo5
```

I got this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libuuid1 : Depends: passwd
            Recommends: uuid-runtime
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Please help. I am new to Ubuntu. so please explain what exactly I did wrong initially, and what is this all about?

Comment: And why are we removing this library?

Answer (score 1):

`libtinfo5` is an important system package that must not be removed unless you really know what you are doing, which is clearly not the case here. You can now reinstall your system.